# Cordova Device Plugin from function

Tags: cordova, plugins

I can use the cordova device plugin successfully straight after the device ready function, device.uui, etc..but if I put the device call in a function it does not work. Can device.uui, device.platform, etc only be used without being in a function

**logUserDevice();**

```
function logUserDevice() {

    //Device information
    var uuid = device.uuid;
    var platform = device.platform;
    var model = device.model;
    var version = device.version;


     //ajax request to the server
      var link = 'server call';
      $.get(link);

}
```

Comment: No it will work.Do you get any error?

Comment: Please call this function in device.ready function it will work